# Flask - 404 not found while requesting URL

Tags: python, flask, web, web-development-server

EDIT: I am using ATOM as my code editor

This is my first flask app. This is the code for api.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/csi/')
def cs():
    return 'Hello, World!'

app.run()
```

I am able to display the home page with the route('/'), however, when I run the URL with extension route('/csi'), it displays 404 not found.

This is what I tried to run:
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/csi`

and got the following error message:

> Not Found 
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: Try removing the trailing `/` from `/csi/`

Comment: The code looks fine. I have tried it with python 3.9.1. Both the routes were working for me.

Comment: So you are running it in ATOM, in that case ATOM is also your web client (most people will use "browser" instead of "web client" - well, web client is the more general term).

Comment: What version of flask are you using? I'm getting [308](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308) for `http://127.0.0.1:5000/csi` instead of [404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)

Answer (score 0):

you're entering the wrong URL
when you code this :

```
@app.route('/csi/')
def cs():
    return 'Hello, World!'

 app.run()
```

your url has to be : `http://127.0.0.1:5000/csi/`